# Import statements in MT940 format

Tags: checking-account

Is there any free software which helps me to import my accounting statements? They come in MT940 format and I would like to transform them to CSV.

Any hint appreciated,
kind regards,

Karsten

Answer (score 2):

Check this out:

https://github.com/sandermarechal/jejik-mt940

PHP module to process mt940.
Written by  sandermarechal, who's my personal hero for writing hearts for linux :)